# How can search the database by month through drop down in php

Tags: php, html-select

Please help me 
I want to search the data of employee by month like january, february etc. by drop down list
and the date field is date type 0000-00-00.How can I search this type of data in php 
thank you..

```
<code>
<select name="month" id="month">
<option>
</option>
<option>
January
</option>
<option>
February
</option>
<option>
March
```

...

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Are you looking for a SQL query to query your database?  How do you want to present the data when you've got what you need for each month?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to give your form options some values for the month numbers.  This will be queried by your database.  You action can be the page that you want to display the data

```
   <form method="post" action="process.php">
    <select name="month" id="month">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
    </select>
   </form>
```

process.php

the "username" and "password" and the database username and password used to connect to the database

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table

//set date_column to the date field in your database
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date_column) = $date";
$result = mysql_query($sql)
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    // Print out the contents of the entry 
    extract($row, EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID, '_');

    //change these to whatever you want to display
    echo "Name: ".$row['column1'];
    echo " Age: ".$row['column2'];

}

?>
```

**EDIT:**
I've rewritten it for you and i've tested it also.  This is presuming you're using MySQLi

This uses prepared statement which make it more secure.  Have a look here for more info http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

In the SELECT statement you can put whatever tables you want but the rest should be good to go.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="testing.php">
    <select name="month" id="month">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

// Include connection file here and replace these variables
$hostname="localhost";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$dbname="dbasename";

 /* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Create statement object
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

// Create a prepared statement
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT name, month, blah FROM test WHERE MONTH(month) = ?")) {

    // Bind your variable to replace the ?
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $month)) {
        //if BIND fails, display an error
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
    }

    // escape the POST data for added protection
    $month = isset($_POST['month'])
          ? $db->real_escape_string($_POST['month'])
          : '';

    // Execute query
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
    }

    // Bind your result columns to variables
    if(!$stmt->bind_result($name, $url, $logo)) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
    }

    // Fetch the result of the query
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $name;
    }

    // Close statement object
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to display all data of particular month when select the particular month in dropdown.The date format in db is yy-mm-dd.I used your code but it's not working.Thanks

Comment: Check out the rewritten post and let me know if you need more help